# Azure LDAP with DirectoryEntry "the server is not operational" error C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have configured secure LDAP in windows azure by using following tutorial:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-configure-secure-ldap/

But I am getting "the server is not operational" error. I am trying to use following code:

```
string DomainPath = "LDAP://0.0.0.0:636";
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath, "someone@example.com", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("usergroup");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");//first name
SearchResult result;
SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();
if (resultCol != null)
{
   for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
   {
      string UserNameEmailString = string.Empty;
      result = resultCol[counter];
      if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname") && result.Properties.Contains("mail") &&
                                result.Properties.Contains("displayname"))
      {
          Users objSurveyUsers = new Users();
          objSurveyUsers.Email = (String)result.Properties["mail"][0] +
                                  "^" + (String)result.Properties["displayname"][0];
          objSurveyUsers.UserName = (String)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0];
          objSurveyUsers.DisplayName = (String)result.Properties["displayname"][0];
          lstADUsers.Add(objSurveyUsers);
      }
   }
}
```

I have also tried to connect my Ip and domain in ldp.exe software it is also giving error failed to connect.

My question is that can I use DirectoryEntry in azure platform to fetch users?

If not so what is the purpose of LDAP in Azure?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you resolved the problem? I have the same problem. If you resolved it, please share me the information. And what is the purpose of LDAP in Azure?

Answer (score -2):

On Azure, the way with best practice to fetch users from Azure AD is using Azure AD Graph API, please refer to the [overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-graph-api/) to know it.

There are two ways for using AAD Graph API which include [REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx) & [SDK](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet).

As reference, there is an article introduced how to do the operations on users using Graph API and supply sample codes for different programming languages, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations.

Comment: Try answering the question asked, there may be a lot of reasons why you want to use LDAPS such as not wanting to rewrite complex software. If you don't know the answer to the question then don't answer. This should have been a comment as it makes no attempt at answering the question.

Comment: The LDAPS access in Azure is *not* to the Azure AD, but for the Azure AD domain Service managed domain, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082341/1555496